# How to array ID from listview and delete from the firebase database in Android

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I want delete the data from the listview in firebase database when the user swip the list view.

1. first I don't know how to get the listview array ID.
2. second I don't know how to delete the data from the listview in firebase.

Here is my code:

```
  listViewInfo.setMenuCreator(creator);
    listViewInfo.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new SwipeMenuListView.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(int position, SwipeMenu menu, int index) {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    Log.d("myTag", "DONE"+ (infoList));
                    break;
                case 1:

                    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                   DatabaseReference de = db.getReference("HiringWalker").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                   de.removeValue();
                    break;
            }
            // false : close the menu; true : not close the menu
            return false;
        }
    });


 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    ref2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            infoList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot infoSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                ReWalker ReWalker = infoSnapshot.getValue(ReWalker.class);
                infoList.add(ReWalker);

                //for read all the data
                //for (DataSnapshot infomationsnap : infoSnapshot.getChildren()){

                // ReWalker ReWalker = infomationsnap.getValue(ReWalker.class);
                // infoList.add(ReWalker);

                //}
            }
            InfoList adapter = new InfoList(Up_coming_service.this, infoList);
            listViewInfo.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

here is my firebase:

[image]

I only want to delete chil (-LWjG....) when the user swip the listview by array id.

Comment: and what does the code you have shared do now when it is ran?